# Passing markup into a Rails Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, erb, partial

Is there any way of doing something equivilant to this:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/outer'  do %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/inner' %>
<% end %>
```

Resulting in

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously there would need to be a way of marking up 'shared/outer.html.erb' to indicate where the passed in partial should be rendered:

```
<div class="outer">
     <% render Here %>
</div>
```

In my specific case I have a generic page header, consisting of a header and subheader, that is shared across all pages, but would like the option of passing in page-specific markup to that header to be rendered below the title and subtitle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `content_for` :

```
<% content_for :subheader do %>
    <%= render partial: 'shared/inner'  do %>
<% end %>

<%= render partial: 'shared/outer' %>
```

Then in shared/outer :

```
<div class="outer">
  <%= yield(:subheader) %>
</div>
```

You can put whatever you'd like in the `content_for` block and use it as many times as you'd like, just change the key name (here `subheader`)

Comment: Thanks. That is the approach I'm currently using, but it seems unnecessarily indirect. It would be much clearer to nest as this is analogous to standard markup.